# Leave async timer

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm sorry I'm a very beginner in JS. The following code stucks at the third line. In the background_mine method. I don't have access to this method, so how can I reset the code after 2 minutes stucking in this method

```
Mining = async () => {
console.log(`## rebalance: ${await getBalance(account, wax.api.rpc)}`);
let mine_work = await background_mine(account)
}
```

Comment: that means `background_mine` returns a `Promise` which hangs. If you can't share more details nobody will be able to help

Comment: @GuerricP Yea. I know. But how can I quit this loop if it hangs?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to implement a timeout?

Comment: @GuerricP Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement a timeout, you can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) like this:

```js
const background_mine = account => new Promise(() => {});

const promisifiedTimeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('Timed out'), 5000));

(async () => {
  const account = {};
  try {
    const result = await Promise.race([background_mine(account), promisifiedTimeout]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to do a [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Example working properly:

```js
const background_mine = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('background_mine'), 500);
});
const limitChecker = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('background_failed'), 1000);
});

const result = await Promise.race([background_mine, limitChecker])
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(`This timed out`);
  });

console.log(result); //background_mine
```

Example having a timeout:

```js
const background_mine = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('background_mine'), 500);
});
const limitChecker = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('background_failed'), 1000);
});

const result = await Promise.race([background_mine, limitChecker])
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(`This timed out`);
  });

console.log(result); //undefined
```

If you check, it all depends on wether background_mine functions is below or above the limitChecker timeout value.